# How to flip the order of sequence header names using specific 'middle point'

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am looking for a way to simply change the order of chunks of a sequence header name in UNIX.

The sequence name I have now is:

```
>PIENAPT00000000258_pienapg00000000172
```

But I need:

```
>pienapg00000000172_PIENAPT00000000258
```

I tried to accomplish this with sed, but realised this is not the way to go. But unfortunately did not find a solution yet. Can someone help me?

```
sed -E 's/PIENAPT.+\_pienapg.+/pienapg.+\_PIENAPT.+//'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following with `sed` specifically.

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)\(_\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/'  Input_file
```

OR in case you have `>` in starting of your Input_file's lines which was NOT clear because of quote tags try following then.

```
sed 's/\(^>\)\([^_]*\)\(_\)\(.*\)/\1\4\3\2/'  Input_file
```

OR as per @potong sir's comment try:

```
sed -E 's/>(.*)_(.*)/>\2_\1/'  Input_file
```

---

---

Trust me this should be pretty easy with `awk` try following if you are ok with it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {print $2,$1}'  Input_file
```

OR in case you have `>` in starting of your Input_file's lines which was NOT clear because of quote tags try following then.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {print substr($1,1,1)$2,substr($1,2)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed -E 's/>(.*)_(.*)/>\2_\1/' file` would be clearer?

Comment: @potong, Thank you, added this solution in my post now, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `>` and `_` as filed separator with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[>_]"}{print ">" $3 "_" $2}' file
```

Output:

```
>pienapg00000000172_PIENAPT00000000258
```